# Unable to See Network Clients during Deauth Capture Issue

Tags: aircrack-ng, deauth-attack

bit of a general question here, would hope to learn more about exactly what is going on technically.

I'm attempting to test and capture a handshake from my own AP (an older Apple Airport router).

I've used various tools from airgeddon to wifite to fluxion to manual airodump-ng and the weird thing is: I cannot see a single client connect to the AP.

But my laptop and two mobile devices are connected. I've even disabled/enabled WiFi on the mobile device during a fluxion passive listening attack, mdk3 doesn't work, nothing sees any clients.

I've also run the same experiment on a new Airport Extreme AP, and it captures just fine and sees clients.

For this, I'm using an ALFA adapter with the Ralink RT3070 chipset (802.11b/g/n) @ 2.4Ghz.

I'll boot up the Nano which I just got recently next, but just curious as to WHY various tools are unable to see clients, therefore unable to deauth (or even passively listen) to ultimately capture the CAP

Comment: Are you sure clients are only using 2.4 GHz?

Comment: The AP is configured to only serve a 2.4Ghz network and I’m scanning only for 2.4Ghz clients and APs with a 2.4Ghz card. Thought 5Ghz might be the issue but...

Comment: Are you hopping channels or on the same channel as AP?

Comment: Same channel as the AP. It’s strange.

Comment: Was able to capture the handshake after switching to an mdk4 attack, seems some APs are immune to MDK3 now.

Comment: yeah, airgeddon has an option to switch between mdk3 and mdk4

Answer (score 0):

If all the tools are failing... the most probably answer is that the problem is not related to the tools. Probably you have some problem on your driver or on your OS installation.

In theory, the chipset you have is able to be set in monitor mode, capture handshakes, etc... at least on airgeddon. Check the "whitelist" of the fully working cards: https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon/wiki/Cards%20and%20Chipsets